# Qt Quick adding gradient frame around Image

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

I am working on application using `Qt 5.4.1` and its `Qt Quick` module. I load some .svg pictures from `/images` directory and then show them in `ListView`, which works ok. But, how do I add shadow gradient around every loaded .svg image? Here is MWE:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2

import Qt.labs.folderlistmodel 2.1

Rectangle
{
    id: ueMainWindow

    visible: true

    width: 800
    height: 1280

    color: "black"

    property string ueRootDirectory:"/images"
    property real ueImagesLoadProgress;
    property bool ueImageLoading;

    Rectangle
    {
        id: ueContainerThumbnails

        antialiasing: true

        color: "black"

        anchors.bottom: ueMainWindow.bottom
        width: ueMainWindow.width

        height: 256

        gradient: Gradient
        {
            GradientStop { position: 0.0; color: "black" }
            GradientStop { position: 1.0; color: "grey" }
        }

        Text
        {
            id: ueTextImageName

            antialiasing: true

            color: "white"

            anchors.horizontalCenter: ueContainerThumbnails.horizontalCenter

            text: qsTr("TestApp")
        }

        ListView
        {
            id: ueViewThumbnails

            antialiasing: true

            orientation: ListView.Horizontal

            anchors
            {
                topMargin: parent.height-(parent.height-50)
                fill: parent
            }

            FolderListModel
            {
                id: ueModelImages

                folder: "file://"+ueRootDirectory
                nameFilters: ["*.svg"]
            }

            Component
            {
                id: ueDelegateImage

                Image
                {
                    id: ueImage

                    source: ueModelImages.folder + "/" + fileName

                    antialiasing: true

                    asynchronous: true

                    horizontalAlignment: Image.AlignHCenter
                    verticalAlignment: Image.AlignVCenter

                    width: 192
                    height: 192

                    fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
                }
            }

            focus: true
            spacing: 10
            leftMargin: 10
            rightMargin: 35
            visible: ueModelImages.status==FolderListModel.Ready

            model: ueModelImages
            delegate: ueDelegateImage
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not exactly clear what you mean by "shadow gradient". Post an image with the effect you aim to achieve.

Comment: @ddriver I want to put a "frame" around the image, and that frame is a gradient from black to white color.

Comment: In that case "shadow" is misleading, a shadow is something that is supposed to represent a projection of some shape.

Comment: @ddriver you are right, but I did not know how to describe it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you should put that gradient into your delegate somehow. You can either:

- create an empty `Item` and put the `Rectangle` and `Image` inside it

example:

```
Component {
    id: ueDelegateImage
    Item { // container
        Rectangle {
            // gradient rectangle
        }
        Image {
            // image
        }
    }
}
```

- or put the `Image` inside the `Rectangle`

example:

```
Component {
    id: ueDelegateImage        
    Rectangle {
        // gradient rectangle acts as a container
        Image {
            // image
        }            
    }  
}
```

In both cases stacking order will draw the gradient rectangle behind the image. A delegate should only have one root element, but is not limited to just one element, you can nest as many as you like.

Comment: does this approach imposes heavy load on hardware if, for instance, I have 500 .svg files with gradient rectangle in ListView, what do you think?

Comment: The overhead will be the SVG files, not the gradients. QtQuick2 uses an optimized renderer, which is very good at drawing a lot of the same object. Besides, the list view loads elements on demand, it is not like all of them are loaded at the same time, it only shows the ones currently fitting on the screen and a few before and after that are cached